# MultiThread Server in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, server

I've to make a project of a synchronous TCP server and I started with an example of the boost library, the main problem is I would like to make a multithread server, actually with the example code server is just able to accept one connection per time. I've read carefully the documentation but I'm not understanding which function is invoked when a new request has been receved to the server.
Conceptually I understand how to operate, I've the launch a new thread when a new connection request is arrived, but by reading code i don't know how to start.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
 
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
 
std::string make_daytime_string()
{
  using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime;
  time_t now = time(0);
  return ctime(&now);
}
 
class tcp_connection
  : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_connection>
{
public:
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<tcp_connection> pointer;
 
  static pointer create(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
  {
    return pointer(new tcp_connection(io_service));
  }
 
  tcp::socket& socket()
  {
    return socket_;
  }
 
  void start()
  {
    message_ = make_daytime_string();
 
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message_),
        boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }
 
private:
  tcp_connection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service)
  {
  }
 
  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& /*error*/,
      size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
  {
  }
 
  tcp::socket socket_;
  std::string message_;
};
 
class tcp_server
{
public:
  tcp_server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13))
  {
    start_accept();
  }
 
private:
  void start_accept()
  {
    tcp_connection::pointer new_connection =
      tcp_connection::create(acceptor_.get_io_service());
 
    acceptor_.async_accept(new_connection->socket(),
        boost::bind(&tcp_server::handle_accept, this, new_connection,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }
 
  void handle_accept(tcp_connection::pointer new_connection,
      const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      new_connection->start();
    }
 
    start_accept();
  }
 
  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};
 
int main()
{
  try
  {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp_server server(io_service);
    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This example of server only sends data. You should do something similar for reading. Asynchronous code may look harder (this is done in this example), but it is much easier then use of synchronous API with threads.

Comment: Actually Server just need to send data, clients have to read only, so the example is perfect for what I need to make.
The main problem is that long textual information has to been sent, instead of a simple datetime and I've to accept more connection requests at the same time

Comment: So `tcp_connection::start` writes first message and next message should be send from `tcp_connection::handle_write`.

Comment: Excatly, this means tcp_connection::handle_write should be without body

Comment: If after sending you don't want to do anything else you can just leave this empty yes. After that function is over it will automatically close the tcp connection socket and delete the `tcp_connection` instance

Comment: But how to accept more connection at the same time?